# JQuery Validation issue with accepting only digits.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form I am trying to validate. This is the `html`

```
<h2>Personal Details</h2>
            <p>Please enter in some information about you.</p>
            <div id="form-row">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" required/>
            </div>
            <div id="form-row">
                <label>Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" name="telephone" value="" id="telephone" required/>
            </div>
            <div id="form-row">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="email" required/>
    </div>
```

I need to use some form of `validation` so I opted to use `jQuery` validation plugin called `.validate`. This is my `script`

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    //When the form is submitted do this...
    $("#stripe-payment-form").submit(function(event) {

        //Validation
        // just for the demos, avoids form submit
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
        });

        $( "#stripe-payment-form" ).validate({
            rules: {
                telephone: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                    }
            }
        });
```

When the page loads the first time I get no errors and validation is working. However If input 'aaa' into the `telephone` input I get this error and no validation occurs:

```
TypeError: $.validator is undefined
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I was following along the documentation on

http://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method

Comment: For starters, don't put your setDefaults code in the submit function, as it will get run every time the form is submitted. Leave it in the doc.ready

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, IIRC, this is not the first time we have to say that to you...

Comment: My id's are unique...name, telephone, email? If your talking about the `divs` I can see that but I don't see how they would affect the issue im having at present

Comment: '<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>' have you included these files

Comment: Maybe you have included validator codes before jquery core?

Comment: Could it be to do with `wp_enqueue_script` calling the file before `jQuery` is loaded? and if this is the case, why does it not happen the first time the page is loaded...

Comment: @Javacadabra This is unrelated to your current issue, that's why i posted it as comment BUT maybe it will be in a near futur **so WHY** using invalid HTML markup???

Comment: **DO NOT** put the `.validate()` or `.setDefaults()` methods inside of a `submit()` handler... it's worse than putting them inside of a `click()` handler, which is also no good. The `.validate()` method is just used for ***initializing*** the plugin on your form! The submit is then captured automatically by the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `jquery.validate.js` file after jquery, like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also, your javascript code should look more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#stripe-payment-form" ).validate({
        rules: {
            telephone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
                }
        }
    });
});
```

No need to wrap it in the form submit event.  It will do that by itself.  If there are other things you want to do on form submit, use the [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) option.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do your code by developing a function and calling it according to your requirement.

```
var only_Number;
$(function(){
    $('.onlynumber').keypress(function(){
        return only_Number();
    });

    only_Number=function(evt){
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Also have a look on codepen: http://codepen.io/ahmadasjad/pen/bNMmya